# ubuntu 14.04 not detecting SamsungY Android via usb cable

Tags: usb, 14.04, android, connection

I had this same problem when previously using ubuntu 13.10, among other issues with my Windows dual boot. So I wiped the hard drive, re-installed ubuntu stand alone, and I still get the same dang error!

```
Error message:
**'Unable to access “BCM21553 Thunderbird”'**  !and 
**'Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001,004]'**
```

Sorry, screenshot to upload since "You need at least 10 reputation to post images???"

I searched several forums previously and finally found a solution.

However, when I rebooted later, the error still comes up and I don't remember which solution worked originally.

Please help!

Thanks,
~ loco

also, I get several Software Updater failure errors (don't know if this coincides with this or other ubuntu problems)

`MOBILE:  Samsung Y GT-S5360 Android 2.3.5 gingerbread`

`LAPTOP:  Samsung 64-bit AMD E-450 APU with Radeon HD Graphics × 2`

Comment: i have a samsung galaxy ace and i get the same warning. but when i tap to turn on mass storage, it would mount. that is the only thing i need it for is to transfer files. i do not get what you would want to do apart from this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem yesterday with a friends phone.  I had to go into synaptic, and install `mtp-tools`.

Once installed, the phone connected OK.

[image]