# Unable to access “BCM21553 Thunderbird and Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001,004]' when connecting SamsungY Android device

Tags: usb, android

see same problem under previous post:

[ubuntu 14.04 not detecting SamsungY Android via usb cable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464653/ubuntu-14-04-not-detecting-samsungy-android-via-usb-cable)

any help would greatly appreciated!

~ loco

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you are going to have to work around this issue.

Strongly recommend you ONLY use (older) 'mass storage' mode, for Android 2.x or 3.x.

---

While MTP has been improved, and does work well on more recent devices, you need to be using at least Android 4.2.2 to see any advantage. *I have had no recent issues with Android 4.2.2 or 4.4, when connecting a device to **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**, **13.10** or **14.04 LTS**.*

The various smartphone vendors, and Google / Android, will NOT be making any further attempts to improve MTP for earlier Android variants. Nor will Canonical (or other open source contributors) be able to make the Ubuntu end of this puzzle work any better.